# Draw tikz figure outside of area

Tags: tikz-pgf

I will like to place the black box, with the number and the chapter outside of the line of the text. I will like place it 1 cm to the right.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt,oldfontcommands,standalone]{memoir}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}    


\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGEr{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}} %used to set the number in chapter section
\makeatother    

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makechapterstyle{box}{
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\HUGEr\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
        \flushright
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm) node[color=white]  (test) {};
        \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
        \draw[color=white] (-0.5,0) rectangle (-0.1,2) node[midway,rotate = 90,color=black] () {Chapter};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\HUGE\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}
}
\chapterstyle{box}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}  
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: graphical explanation]

Comment: try `...\begin{tikzpicture}\hspace*{1cm}...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\hspace*{1cm}` inside the `tikzpicture` environment works. Alternatively, you can also redefine the bounding box of the `tikzpicture` (which can be useful in other scenarios as well -- see p.175ff., *Establishing a Bounding Box* in [the PGF manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)). As a side note: I would generally advise against mixing relative and absolute lengths inside a `tikzpicture` for placement, if you can avoid it. If you keep everything relative (so: `(2,-2)` instead of `(2cm,-2cm)`), it makes your code more flexible, plus there's less typing (sometimes it can't be avoided, of course, this is just my personal preference at which I've arrived over the years).

Result:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt,oldfontcommands,standalone]{memoir}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}    


\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGEr{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}} %used to set the number in chapter section
\makeatother    

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makechapterstyle{box}{
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\HUGEr\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
        \flushright
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % Either version works -- use whichever is preferred or comes with fewer undesirable
            % side effects for the particular scenario.
            %\hspace*{1cm}
            \path[use as bounding box] (-1,0) rectangle (1,2); %will scale with tikzpicture units

            \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[color=white]  (test) {};
            \draw[color=white] (1,1) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
            \draw[color=white] (-0.5,0) rectangle (-0.1,2) node[midway,rotate = 90,color=black] () {Chapter};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\HUGE\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}
}
\chapterstyle{box}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}  
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```